# NSURLSessionTask. Suspend does not work

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

This is what Apple's documentation says regarding `suspend` method of `NSURLSessionTask` class

> A task, while suspended, produces no network traffic and is not subject to timeouts.

Ok. So I'm running the following simple code:

```
        let url   = NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/delay/10")!
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        self.task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urlRequest.URL!, completionHandler: {

            data, response, error in print("completion ERROR \(error)")
        })

        self.task.resume()

        print("Start")
        delay(5, closure: {

            self.task.suspend()

            print("Suspend")
        })
```

Function `delay` is simply a wrapper around `dispatch_after` and a request to `http://httpbin.org/delay/10` gives response after 10 seconds. In the middle of waiting for response I suspend the task. However that does not work. In 60 seconds the completion block is called with timeout error. Can anybody please explain what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show the wrapper around `dispatch_after`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This appears to be normal behaviour, however more definitive documentation from Apple would be useful in clarifying what we are seeing.**

Apple’s documentation does not provide a detailed explanation of how suspend works, or when it should be used. However, **my view** (based on testing and research) is that `suspend()` should only be used for download
tasks. Data tasks should only use `resume()` (to start the task) and `cancel()` when appropriate.

My testing, using Xcode and Charles Proxy, revealed a suspended data task has no effect on the network traffic as indicated in Apple’s documentation. In other words, network traffic is produced.

**I observed two things using suspend and data tasks:**

1) If it's called right after resume, it has no effect on the data task. It does not suspend network traffic and barring no network or server side-side issues, a successful response is received in the callback.

2) If it's called in the `dispatch.asyncAfter` callback, it still does not suspend the network traffic, however the callback gets a “request timeout” error instead of a successful response. According to Charles Proxy, the request is successful though. It is this result that leads me to believe that `suspend()` should not be be used with data tasks. The result of this callback is essentially useless in my opinion.

**Cancelling a data task:**

`cancel()` works as expected. The client (you) closes the connection before getting a complete response from the server. This can be done right after calling `resume()` or at a later time (before the request has completed of course).

Comment: "The request timed out."? What is that? The error passed into the completion block? So it works for you just like for me, therefore it is normal behaviour for a suspended task, right? If yes, then why do we need suspend at all? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Sorry, it seems I misinterpreted your question. I thought you were not seeing the “Suspend” message in the console.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha You are right, I have updated my answer to provide more details. It appears to be normal behaviour for a data task. A download task would presumably not get passed to the completion block until the task is resumed and completed.

Answer (score 0):

I accept that suspend() has no effect on URLSessionDataTask

```
                    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in                        
                    print("response is received all the time")
                    }
                }
                dataTask.resume()
                dataTask.suspend()
```

However when I try cancelling it does

```
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in                        
                    print("response is cancelled")
                    }
                }
                dataTask.resume()
                dataTask.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call dataTask with **URLRequest** and set timeoutInterval to **.infinity**. (default is 60s)

```swift
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.timeoutInterval = .infinity
task = session.dataTask(with: request)
task?.resume()
```