# still timeout after I suspend NSURLSessionDataTask in AFN3.1.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlsessiondatatask

I init NSURLSessionDataTask with follow method

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

then call `setDataTaskDidReceiveResponseBlock` and `setDataTaskDidReceiveDataBlock` to write data to file.
and then I call `suspend` but the after the timeoutInterval I get completionHandler with timeout error.

the document about suspend:
`/*
 * Suspending a task will prevent the NSURLSession from continuing to
 * load data.  There may still be delegate calls made on behalf of
 * this task (for instance, to report data received while suspending)
 * but no further transmissions will be made on behalf of the task
 * until -resume is sent.  The timeout timer associated with the task
 * will be disabled while a task is suspended. -suspend and -resume are
 * nestable. 
 */`

I want to know how to suspend the task,and why I call suspend like this it does not work

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me. I did several tests, it seems that there is nothing with AFN, you can suspend a NSURLSessionDownloadTask, but not NSURLSessionDataTask. I have no idea about the reason.

Update:I found this post: [NSURLSessionTask. Suspend does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662007/nsurlsessiontask-suspend-does-not-work)